# Can I set gulp livereload to run after all files are compiled?

Tags: javascript, pug, gulp, stylus

I've got a gulp set up to work with Stylus, Jade and tiny-lr. My problem is that when I save one jade file, it start's compiling them all, therefore live reloading fires on the first file copied to the destination, before the file I am working on currently is compiled, resulting in me having to refresh manually. I have fixing this issue using "gulp-changed" but I don't seem to be able to configure it or something. Anyone had this problem before? I am posting my Gulp file so you can take a look.

A timeline diagram of the problem can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3g37oy25s9mq969/jade_compile_frefresh_problem.png?dl=0

Any help is appreciated!

```
    'use strict';

    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var jade = require('gulp-jade');
    var gutil = require('gulp-util');
    var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
    var jeet = require('jeet');
    var nib = require('nib');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var lr = require('tiny-lr')();
    // var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

    // Define sources object
    var sources = {
      jade: "jade/**/*.jade",
      partials: "partials/**/*.jade",
      stylus: "styl/**/*.styl",
      scripts: "js/**/*.js"
    };

    // Define destinations object

    var destinations = {
      html: "dist/",
      css: "dist/css",
      js: "dist/js"
    };

    // Compile and copy Jade
    gulp.task("jade", function(event) {
      return gulp.src(sources.jade)
      .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
      })).pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.html));
    });

    // Compile and copy Stylus
    gulp.task("stylus", function(event) {
      return gulp.src(sources.stylus).pipe(stylus({
        use: [nib(), jeet()],
        import: [
          'nib',
          'jeet'
        ],
        style: "compressed"
      })).pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.css));
    });

    // Minify and copy all JavaScript
    gulp.task('scripts', function() {
      gulp.src(sources.scripts)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
    });

    // Consolidate Bower Files and copy to /dist/js/
    // gulp.task('bower-files', function() {
    //   return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(/* options */), {})
    //     .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
    // });

    // Watch for file changes and execute tasks
    gulp.task("watch", function() {
      gulp.watch(sources.jade, ["jade"]);
      gulp.watch(sources.partials, ["jade"]);
      gulp.watch(sources.stylus, ["stylus"]);
      gulp.watch(sources.scripts, ["scripts"]);
      gulp.watch('dist/**/*', refresh);
    });

    // Live Reload
    gulp.task('serve', function () {
      var express = require('express');
      var app = express();
      app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
      app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist/'));
      app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');
      lr.listen(35729);
    });

    // Define default task
    gulp.task("default", ["jade", "stylus", "scripts", "serve", "watch"]);

    // Refresh function
    var refresh = function(event) {
      var fileName = require('path').relative(__dirname, event.path);
      gutil.log.apply(gutil, [gutil.colors.magenta(fileName), gutil.colors.cyan('built')]);
      lr.changed({
        body: { files: [fileName] }
      });
    };
```

Comment: it's not recommended to link external files as such in case the links die, as this one did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have achieve this by writing a simple javascript function in my gulpfile.js

I did this because when I compile my sass files, livereload will run around 10 times, this method will make it only run once.

My `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    $.livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch([
        path.join(config.path.app, 'media/js/**/*.js'),
        path.join(config.path.app, 'media/css/**/*.css'),
        path.join(config.path.app, 'templates/**/*.html')
    ]).on('change', stackReload);

    // a timeout variable
    var timer = null;

    // actual reload function
    function stackReload() {
        var reload_args = arguments;

        // Stop timeout function to run livereload if this function is ran within the last 250ms
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);

        // Check if any gulp task is still running
        if (!gulp.isRunning) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $.livereload.changed.apply(null, reload_args);
            }, 250);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for gulp.isRunning ? 

I can't find any other use of it, or in the Gulp API.

Comment: what is arguments. When you say: var reload_args = arguments;

Answer (score 3):

I have done it. What I had to do is create a new task called "Reload", put dependencies on it and run it after each of the other tasks. Here is the new Gulpfile":

'use strict';

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var jeet = require('jeet');
var nib = require('nib');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var sources = {
  jade: "jade/**/*.jade",
  partials: "partials/**/*.jade",
  stylus: "styl/**/*.styl",
  scripts: "js/**/*.js"
};

// Define destinations object
var destinations = {
  html: "dist/",
  css: "dist/css",
  js: "dist/js"
};

// Compile and copy Jade
gulp.task("jade", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.jade)
  .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.html))
});

// Compile and copy Stylus
gulp.task("stylus", function(event) {
  return gulp.src(sources.stylus).pipe(stylus({
    use: [nib(), jeet()],
    import: [
      'nib',
      'jeet'
    ],
    style: "compressed"
  })).pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.css));
});

// Minify and copy all JavaScript
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(sources.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
});

// Server
gulp.task('server', function () {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist/'));
  app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');
});

// Watch sources for change, executa tasks
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(sources.jade, ["jade", "refresh"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.partials, ["jade", "refresh"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.stylus, ["stylus", "refresh"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.scripts, ["scripts", "refresh"]);
});

// Refresh task. Depends on Jade task completion
gulp.task("refresh", ["jade"], function(){
  livereload.changed();
  console.log('LiveReload is triggered');
});

// Define default task
gulp.task("default", ["jade", "stylus", "scripts", "server", "watch"]);
```

Comment: According to the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload#livereloadchangedpath, `Calling this function (livereload-changed) without a path will do nothing.`  You have found differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gulp-livereload](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload) and write your own callback which send reload event when you want it:

```
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = function(gulp) {
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
        livereload.listen();
        gulp.watch([
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/**/*.js'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../index.html')
        ]).on('change', function(event) {
            livereload.changed();
            console.log('File', event.path, 'was', event.type);
            console.log('LiveReload is triggered');
        });
    });
};
```

**UPD:** So, for your case you can do this in this way:

1) Install `gulp-livereload`:

```
npm install gulp-livereload --save-dev
```

2) Include `gulp-livereload` in your `gulpfile.js`

```
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
```

3) Replace your old code with `watch` task, I mean that:

```
// Watch for file changes and execute tasks
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch(sources.jade, ["jade"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.partials, ["jade"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.stylus, ["stylus"]);
  gulp.watch(sources.scripts, ["scripts"]);
  gulp.watch('dist/**/*', refresh);
});
```

And replace it with new code:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch([
        sources.jade,
        sources.partials,
        sources.stylus,
        sources.scripts,
        'dist/**/*'
    ]).on('change', function(event) {
        livereload.changed();
        console.log('File', event.path, 'was', event.type);
        console.log('LiveReload is triggered');
    });
});
```

4) Of cource check that this configuration fits to your requirements.

Comment: Can you help me integrate this logic into my current setup? I'm not very good with JS :(

Comment: I can see it better now. But if I replace it they way you show me, Gulp will stop firing the corresponding tasks when a file is changed, meaning it won't compile Jade and Stylus files. What I will try is to combine what I've with the code you supplied. I will write to say if it worked! :)

Comment: Actually when I look at it more closely, it seems like it does the same thing as my old configuration - meaning it refreshes on the first file changed. The thing is that I've got about 10 jade files and when I save one of them, it compiles them all. Therefore, the 'changed' event fires on the first file copied to the destination folder and refreshes before the file I am looking at in the browser is compiled. I will try to make a graph and post it so the problem is clear.

Comment: Added a diagram to the description I hope this clears things up :)

Comment: Gulp is based on streams, so actually, you can set dependencies task for it. I think, it's the only way to resolve this.

Comment: Had no one worked with more than 5 jade files? This should be a common problem, I can't believe no one had it! All I need is to execute some code after a Gulp task has completely finished... I have even tried promieses but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when compiling typescript and then refreshing using livereload.  To solve the problem, I created "watch tasks" that run a refresh task once the work is finished.

Below is a minimal code sample taken from your question with the pattern that I've used:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var sources = {
  jade: "jade/**/*.jade"
};

var destinations = {
  html: "dist/"
};

// Compile and copy Jade
gulp.task("jade", function() {
  return gulp.src(sources.jade)
  .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.html));
});

gulp.task('refresh', function() { return livereload.reload(); });

// execute task, then when finished, refresh
gulp.task("watch-jade", ["jade"], function() { return gulp.start('refresh'); });

gulp.task("watch", function() {  
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(sources.jade, ["watch-jade"]);
});
```