# Is there a way to tell when Gulp is finished with all tasks or when it's executing, or ...?

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-watch

Is there any way to tell when Gulp is completely finished executing tasks? i.e., like a "finished" emit or the like?

Or even when all changes are done in a watch?

I want to run livereload() ONLY when everything is done, both so I don't have to livereload() multiple times and so the reload happens after, say, all TS files are compiled completely.

I saw this SE question, [Can I set gulp livereload to run after all files are compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384796/can-i-set-gulp-livereload-to-run-after-all-files-are-compiled) but he uses a method that I can't find any documentation for, *gulp.isRunning*

SUMMARIZED GULP FILE:

```
gulp.task( 'compile:typescript', function () {

    var tsResult = tsProject
        .src() // instead of gulp.src(...)
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( ts( tsProject ) );

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write( '.', {includeContent: false, sourceRoot: './app'} ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( args.dest ? gconfig[args.dest].js : gconfig.dev.js ) )
        ;
} )
;


gulp.task( 'watch', function () {
    livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch( [gconfig.source.typescript], ['compile:typescript'] );
} );

process.on('exit',function(){
    livereload.reload(gconfig.source.index);
});
```

Comment: What does your gulpfile look like? This should probably work out of the box, if you have tasks depend on eachother properly, as well as have them return a stream.

Comment: Adding the Gulp file to the question now, thanks.

Comment: Woa, that helps, but it helps a bit too much. Any chance you can trim it down a bit? It's much more likely we can usefully help if the repro is minimal. See [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: Whoops! Here you go. Thanks!

Comment: Try upgrading to Gulp4. There were some fundamental problems in Gulp3 around task scheduling which have been addressed in v4. Upgrading solved many of these problems for me.